# How to prevent software(skype) stays on foreground

Tags: windows-8.1, skype

My Skype stuck on foreground and I can't minimize it, unless I click on Minimize Button or Close Button.
The normal is when you click in other window or program this will be on foreground and the other window/program that was open will go to background. With Skype I need click minimize or close every time and this s*cks!

This issue happen only with Skype.

Thanks in advance.

*I'm using Windows 8.1*

*I'm using Skype for desktop version*

Comment: have you applied all updates and tried to reinstall skype?

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is an old question;
still, I was having this issue a couple of days ago, so here it is.
(I'm using Skype in Linux, but it should be the same)
Open the "Tools" menu, go to Settings.
In "Calling" section you should find "Show call window when Skype is in the background"; turn this option off.
I hope this helps!!!